# Django rest framework router urls is not working

Tags: javascript, django, django-rest-framework

So, I have such viewset.

```
class ProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = Profile.objects.all()
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )

@action(detail=True, methods=['PUT'])
def set_description(self, request, pk=None):
    profile = self.get_object()
    serializer = DescriptionSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        profile.description = request.data['description']
        profile.save()
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors,
                        status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

@action(
    detail=True,
    methods=['post'],
    serializer_class=ImageSerializer
)
def add_image(self, request, pk=None):
    instance = self.get_object()
    serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=self.request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    image = serializer.save(profile=request.user.profile)
    image_id = image.id
    return Response(serializer.data, {'image_id': image_id})

@action(
    detail=True,
    methods=['delete'],
    serializer_class=ImageSerializer
)
def delete_image(self, request, pk):
    instance = self.get_object()
    instance.delete()
    return JsonResponse(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

My urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

from . import views
from . import viewsets

app_name = 'profile_'

router = DefaultRouter()


router.register('', viewsets.ProfileViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.ProfileView.as_view(), name='profile'),
]

urlpatterns += router.urls
```

And finally there is a couple of available urls (showed by python3 manange show_urls)

```
/profile/<pk>/add_image/        profile_.viewsets.ProfileViewSet        profile_:profile-add-image
/profile/<pk>/add_image\.<format>/      profile_.viewsets.ProfileViewSet        profile_:profile-add-image
/profile/<pk>/delete_image/     profile_.viewsets.ProfileViewSet        profile_:profile-delete-image
/profile/<pk>/delete_image\.<format>/   profile_.viewsets.ProfileViewSet        profile_:profile-delete-image
/profile/<pk>/set_description/  profile_.viewsets.ProfileViewSet        profile_:profile-set-description
/profile/<pk>/set_description\.<format>/        profile_.viewsets.ProfileViewSet        profile_:profile-set-description
```

I not copied all of them but you can see there is all paths I need provided by default router.
So, I trying to change profile's description from JS

```
this.update(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/${this.user_id}/set_description/`, data, 'PUT')
```

Update is a function which getting url, some king of data and a request method (And it works ok, because I used it so much times).

But server responded with:

```
 profile.js:58 PUT http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/5/set_description/ 404 (Not Found)
```

So, if I try `http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/${this.user_id}/add_image/` it will cause same issue.

All paths exist as you can see in the output above

Where did the problem come from? I will be soooooo gratefull if you help me!
.

Comment: hi, did you test that with/without final slash char?

Comment: I tested it without and got this result:
You called this URL via PUT, but the URL doesn't end in a slash and you have APPEND_SLASH set. Django can't redirect to the slash URL while maintaining PUT data. Change your form to point to 127.0.0.1:8000/profile/5/set_description/ (note the trailing slash), or set APPEND_SLASH=False in your Django settings.

Seems that it's not correct way

Comment: ok, and for a check, do you have any object with pk=5? it maybe because of that there's no such a object!?

Comment: Yeah, I have it.